# How can we Invite friends to app via Facebook? (I am missing a step or two)

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am trying to develop and app where users can invite their Facebook friends to use the app. Because of the new 4.0 SDK, I have had difficulty finding a good step-by-step answer to this problem.

I am unable to get this code to work because I have two errors

1)No known class method selector for presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession

2) Expected "(" with "handler:^(FBSDKAppInviteDialog result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)

the following code is within my IBAction for my button which, once clicked, should lead the user to a list of their Facebook friends.

```
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:NSLocalizedString(@"FBinviteMessage", nil)
 title:nil
 parameters:nil
 handler:^(FBSDKAppInviteDialog result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` to let user invite their friends.

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/YOUR_APP_LINK_ID"]];
//optionally set previewImageURL
//content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

`FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate` delegate methods:

```
- (void)appInviteDialog: (FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults: (NSDictionary *)results {
    NSLog(@"%@", results);
}

- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios